# Normalizing temperature data that is result from auto correlation

Tags: python, signal-processing, correlation

I have a temperature signal and a strain signal.
I have computed the ACF of both signals using `np.correlate(..., "same")`, so now I have get a correlated signal with same length as the inputs.

I correlate the temperature with the strain using `np.correlate(Temperature, Strain,"same")`.

I get a correlated signal, then I shift it by calculating the max peaks.

Now the amplitude of the correlated shifted temperature signal is very high, I want to normalize it to 0 degrees to 40 degrees.

How would I do that?

```
 # ACF between two components
    x1x2 = np.correlate(normalized[:,0], ydatanew, 'same')

    # see the results
    f = plt.figure()
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title('ACF')
    ax.plot(x1x2)
    peaks_indices = signal.find_peaks_cwt(x1x2, np.arange(1,10))
    delta_index = np.argmax(peaks_indices);
    print(delta_index)
    shifted_signal = x1x2[delta_index:]
    f = plt.figure()
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title("shifted temperature Signal")
    ax.plot(shifted_signal)
    # mainloop
    plt.show()
```

[image]

http://www.mediafire.com/file/r7dg7i9dacvpl2j/curve_fitting_ahmed.xlsx/file
data file

Comment: Share the data which we can work on and a code which reproduces this plot

Comment: @Bazingaa I did it

Comment: Read my comment again carefully.

Comment: I shared the data and the code

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to do linear interpolation? If so:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.random.normal(size=20)
numpy.interp(a, (a.min(), a.max()), (0, 40))
array([23.84183492, 26.07583446,  0.        ,  7.39940903, 16.78754596,
       15.42560512, 40.        , 24.08125307, 23.23089914, 24.66628223,
       9.18832629, 26.16217936, 25.04153859, 26.3898786 , 34.59643449,
       25.15859023, 23.27551679, 27.92135125, 15.41054983, 21.61565544])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I mean I'm doing correrlation between strain and temperature, then I get a correrlated signal that is the result of two... I want then to use the result correlated signal against so that I can fit the correlated signal with the strain... but the correlated signal has different amplitudes.. how would I related those to each others ?

Comment: Did you get what I need to do ? Have questions ?

Comment: The problem with your answer is it produces a shorter signal than the original one, which is useless if I want to plot it against any other signal...

Comment: hmm? How so? Input size is 20, and so is the output.

Comment: The problem is after shifting the signal (temperature) I will have different length than the original temperature sensor

Answer (score 0):

I have posted it for a similar answer, with code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057228/power-correlation-between-two-normalized-time-series-signals-in-python/53067065#53067065)

To receive a peak at the right location you have to divide by the number of the summed elements. This can be easily overlooked using the numpy/scipy functions which sums but do not divide by the length.

With respect to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient).