# Power correlation between two normalized time-series signals in Python?

Tags: python, math, time-series, signal-processing, correlation

I have two normalized ([1,0]) signals (images attached). Each signal has many peaks and dips. However, both signal have a maximum at approximately same time (in the attached pics, at 2.5 seconds both signals have maximum value of 1.0). I would to like to run correlation between two signals to have the maximum be at 2.5 s. When I run numpy.correlate, I get a peak at a different time step than where the maximum values are. How can I get a maximum correlation peak at time 2.5 s? Any ideas/suggestions would help greatly. Thanks!

[image: signal 1]

[image: signal 2]

Comment: Correlation isn't going to just match the peaks. If you're just trying to match the peak, then just correlate some window around the peaks? Perhaps you want to correlate the integral instead of the actual signal?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would want to take the whole signal into consideration. If the two signals are measured in real-time, I want to show that the two signals have highest peaks around the same time stamp. I am confused as to how to get a plot that shows that the two peaks have maximum at around same time stamp than anywhere else when compared to each other.

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for the product of the two signals? `numpy.correlate` slides one signal over the other and gives you a total correlation.

Answer (score 0):

To receive a peak at the right location you have to divide by the number of the summed elements. This can be easily overlooked using the numpy/scipy functions which sums but do not divide by the length.

```
from scipy.signal import correlate

corr = correlate(x1, x2, 'same')
norm_arr = np.concatenate((np.arange(x1.size / 2)[::-1], np.arange(x1.size / 2)))
corrected_corr = corr / (samples.size - norm_arr)/(np.std(x1)*np.std(x2))
```

Comment: I have few questions regarding that implementation: Let's say that the array x1 and x2 are of size (600,) each. Then, corr will be (300,) because of [x1.size / 2:]. correct? Also, is the samples.size (300,) as well?

Comment: Yes. You are right. It was taken from autocorrelation implementation and feets only positive time shift. I have edited it. Hope it satisfies you.